# How to remove an object from a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to be able to remove a specific object from my json file so I can renew the time.

At the moment I've tried to use a for loop to find the right one but this doesn't work and it just adds a new object without removing the old one.

How would you be able to remove the old object from the json file?

**nodejs**

```
function updateTime(id,name) {

  var newServer = {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "time": new Date()
  }

  var id = id;

  fs.readFile('servers.json', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    json.push(newServer);


      // for loop to check if the server has already been added in the json file.
      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var id = json[i].id;
          delete json[i][id];
          console.log("removed " + json[i][id]);
          // return;
      }



    fs.writeFile("servers.json", JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved new server!');
      });
   });
}
```

**json file**

```
[
    {
        "id": "728374892403228752",
        "name": "test2",
        "time": "2020-07-02T23:06:59.889Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "725475771321155605",
        "name": "test server",
        "time": "2020-07-02T23:06:59.889Z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove spesific objects in an array you can filter them out. Consider following.

```js
fs.readFile('servers.json', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    json.push(newServer);
    // So you need to have an id of an object to remove
    // so lets say that it's 728374892403228752 this number.
    var idToRemove = 728374892403228752;
    // So this will filter out that object with an id of `idToRemove`
    json = json.filter(child => parseInt(child.id) !== idToRemove);
    // after this you can do your fileWrite again :)
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked when static, but when I change the `var idToRemove` to `var idToRemove = id;` it stops working again. Would you know why this happens?

Comment: Nevermind, I just needed to remove `parseInt`. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Appears that the for-loop would remove the `id` property from each object.

If you'd like to remove the object containing a specific id, you could use the `filter` method on `Array`.

```
json.filter(entry => entry.id !== specificId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the id in the global scope, so you want to make sure they the array of objects has all unique ids

```
function updateTime(id,name) {

  var newServer = {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "time": new Date()
  }

  fs.readFile('servers.json', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    json.push(newServer);


      // for loop to check if the server has already been added in the json file.
      var duplicates = 0
      var newJson = []
       // count the duplicates to make sure there is only one of that object with the id
      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
         if(json[i].id === id) {
           duplicates++
         }
          if(duplicates <=1) {
            newJson.push(json[i])
          }
      }



    fs.writeFile("servers.json", JSON.stringify(newJson, null, 4), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved new server!');
      });
   });
}
```